# C# Outlook 2010 FormRegion and Registry Entries

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, ms-office

I have an Outlook AddIn, which has custom form regions with message class name IPM.Note.XXX (for MailItem related Form Regions) as well as IPM.Appointment.XXX (for AppointmentItem related Form Regions), where XXX varies for different form regions. In a particular issue observed however, it is observed that, on the double click of date in a calendar or on click of a "New Appointment" menu option in the ribbon, my custom form region with IPM.Appointment.XXX is invoked. This is not the intended behavior and no code has been written for such thing to happen. Also, I have checked the registry entries, and those seem to be fine. So can you please let me know, what might be causing this issue?
Thanks,
Bhushan.